# How Application Insight does automatically capture Incoming HttpRequests?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-application-insights

I am quit new to instrumenting with application insight. I just create simple asp.net core web api project and set up application insight for instrumenting. I was noticed when controller is invoked method(GET) it will automatically capture in application insight without any code. how does it happen?

Answer (score 3):

If your question is about "How does Application Insights capture information about incoming requests to the application", then its based on DiagnosticSource events. The Asp.Net Core hosting environment publishes `DiagnosticSource` events, which Application Insights subscribes to, and creates `RequestTelemetry` out of it.
The following shows the exact names of events being listened to:
https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/blob/develop/src/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore/DiagnosticListeners/Implementation/HostingDiagnosticListener.cs#L68

Note: In older versions on the SDK, Requests monitoring was done via a 'RequestTrackingMiddleWare' which is now obsolete.

Additional Info - Similar approach of listening to `DiagnosticSource` events is used to monitor dependencies (http, sql) as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you add Application Insight using Visual Studio it will automatically add `.UseApplicationInsights()` within your `CreateWebHostBuilder` method:

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseApplicationInsights()
                .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

This will add Application Insight to the application pipeline (middleware) that performs the logging.

Further Reading:
[ASP.NET Core Middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x)